# Recorrer dos viewbag sin duplicar

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor, foreach, cshtml

Hola buen dia tengo dos viewbag que quiero recorrer con un foreach y así asignarlos a una select múltiple

pero al hacerlo o no puedo accesar a los datos value o al recorrer me duplica datos

Esto lo quiero hacer ya que es mi vista Edit

el viewbag SoftwareId me trae la lista completa de los elementos mientras que SoftwareId2 me trae la lista de los elementos que se encuentran asociados a el Id de mi elemento MantenimientoSotware al cual lepertenece esta view de editar

la idea básica es tráeme todos los elementos de la lista recórrela y si el elemento de SoftwareId coincide con SoftwareId2 muestralo como `<option value="@dato.Value" selected>` si no muestralo como `<option value="@dato.Value" >@dato.Text</option>`

pero la unica manera que encuentro para acceder al dato Value que representa el Id es dentro de un foreach, si no lo hago de esta forma, no puedo acceder a value

Controlador:

```
 ViewBag.SoftwareId = new SelectList(db.Eq_tblSoftware, "id", "Nombre");
 ViewBag.SoftwareId2 = db.Eq_tblMantenimientoSoftware.Where(p => p.Eq_tblMantenimiento_id == id).Select(p => new SelectListItem() { Value = p.Eq_tblSoftware_id.ToString() }).ToList<SelectListItem>();
```

el primer viewbag me trae la lista de elementos completa
el segundo me trae los elementos relacionados a ese ID
(ya comprobado)

vista

```
 foreach (var dat in ViewBag.SoftwareId)
        {
            foreach (var dato in ViewBag.SoftwareId2)
            {
                if (dato.Value == dat.Value)
                {
                    <option value="@dato.Value" selected>@dato.Text</option>
                }
                else
            {
                <option value="@dato.Value" >@dato.Text</option>
            }
            }
}
```

cabe destacar que la relacion es muchos a muchos entonces en la base de datos se hizo uso de una tabla intermedia

Comment: Hola.  ¿La variable SoftwareId2 de que tipo es?, pregunto porque puedes parsear la variable en lista y preguntar en el mismo if si existe la variable dentro de esa lista (funcion: Contains), así eliminas el foreach padre.

Comment: No entiendo en tu código, para que hacer doble recorrido de el for, si el ítem de tu primer for nunca lo usas.

Comment: Lo siento creo que falto información editare la pregunta